# Is the rank of a matrix with coefficients $\{-1,0,1\}$ the same as the rank of the matrix with coefficients in $GF(3)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, matrix-rank, vector-fields

I have a set of matrices defined over the ring of the integers, which items are using only coefficients -1, 0 and 1. For example:

$$
A = \left(\begin{matrix}
   1 &  0 & -1 \\
  -1 &  1 &  0 \\
   0 &  1 &  0
\end{matrix}\right)
\hspace{1em}
\text{(over }\mathbb{Z}\text{)}
$$

Now I'm wondering, if I transform my matrices into equivalent matrices in GF(3) (mapping 0 to 0, 1 to 1, and -1 to 2), is their rank preserved?

With my example, the transformed matrix is:

$$
A' = \left(\begin{matrix}
  1 & 0 & 2 \\
  2 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)
\hspace{1em}
\text{(over }GF(3)\text{)}
$$

and $\operatorname{rank} A = \operatorname{rank} A' = 3$. Is this result true in general?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the result is not true in general, because $\det(A)$ may be a nonzero multiple of $3$, which becomes $0$ over $\Bbb F_3$. For example,
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1\cr -1 & 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
has determinant $\det(A)=-3$ over $\Bbb Z$, which is $0$ over $\Bbb F_3$.

Comment: Is it possible to have $\det A = 3k$, if all the items of $A$ are in $\{-1,0,1\}$ though?

Comment: Yes, it is, at least for $k=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Take the matrix
$$
M =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It is clearly of full rank over $\mathbb{Z}$ but the transformed is not. We also have that $\det(M) = 3$ hence it is not invertible $\pmod{3}$.